# Firebird/IBPP: How to retrieve ID generated by a database autoincrement?

Tags: c++, sql, firebird

I configured my firebird database to autoincrement the primary key of the table.

```
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID;
SET GENERATOR GEN_CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID TO 0;

CREATE TRIGGER CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SETS_BI FOR CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SETS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
    if (NEW.CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID is NULL) then NEW.CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID = GEN_ID(GEN_CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID, 1);
END
```

Now, in my C++ program using IBPP I have the following problem:

When inserting a dataset into an new row of this table I know all values in my C++ program exept the new primary key because the database creates it. How can I retrieve this key form the database?

Maybe someone else inserted an entry too - just a moment after I inserted one. So retrieve the PK with the highest value could create an error. How can I handle this?

---

Adopting Amir Rahimi Farahani's answer I found the following solution for my problem:

I use a generator:

```
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID;
SET GENERATOR GEN_CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID TO 0;
```

and the following C++/IBPP/SQL code:

```
// SQL statement
m_DbStatement->Execute(
    "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR gen_channel_parameter_set_id FROM rdb$database"
    );

// Retrieve Data
IBPP::Row ibppRow;
int64_t channelParameterSetId;

m_DbStatement->Fetch(ibppRow);
ibppRow->Get (1, channelParameterSetId);


// SQL statement
m_DbStatement->Prepare(
    "INSERT INTO channel_parameter_sets "
    "(channel_parameter_set_id, ...) "
    "VALUES (?, ...) " 
    );      

// Set variables
m_DbStatement->Set (1, channelParameterSetId);
...
...

// Execute
m_DbStatement->Execute ();
m_DbTransaction->CommitRetain ();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to generate and use the new id before inserting the new record:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_CHANNEL_PARAMETER_SET_ID FROM rdb$database
```

You now know the value for new primary key.

**Update:**
IBPP supports `RETURNING` too:

```
// SQL statement
m_DbStatement->Prepare(
    "INSERT INTO channel_parameter_sets "
    "(...) VALUES (...) RETURNING channel_parameter_set_id" 
    );      

// Execute
m_DbStatement->Execute ();
m_DbTransaction->CommitRetain ();

// Get the generated id
m_DbStatement->Get (1, channelParameterSetId);
...
```

Comment: This is a straight forward solution. But I think there is the drawback the counter increments every time the statement (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR ...) is executed even if the insert afterwards fails. Or is there a way to handle this?

Comment: The `BEFORE INSERT` trigger approach has the same effect if the insert fails afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the value of the generated key (or any other column) you can use [`INSERT ... RETURNING ...`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-insert-returning).

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (x, y, z) VALUES (1, 2, 3) RETURNING ID
```

Also a lot of drivers provide extra features to support `RETURNING`, but I don't know IBPP.

Note that from the perspective of a driver the use of `RETURNING` will make the insert act like an executable stored procedure; some drivers might require you to execute it in a specific way.

Comment: Do I have to write my own stored procedure to use the RETURNING command?

Comment: @Ergodicity No you don't need to do that, however a query with `RETURNING` is treated by firebird **as if it is** a stored procedure, and for some drivers that means you need to execute it in a specific way (which is the same way you'd execute an `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`).

Comment: I tried: `INSERT INTO channel_parameter_sets (parameter_set_id, channel_fk, parameter_id_fk, parameter_value) VALUES (1, 2, 14, 42) RETURNING channel_parameter_set_id`. A new row was inserted but unfortunately no value was returned. So I think I will use Amir Rahimi Farahani's solution. Even your's is seems to be more elegant.

Comment: @Ergodicity See the last edit from Amir, that is what I meant.